# Put Type information to empty parameters method call in Scala

Tags: function, scala, generics

I am trying to create Guava TreeMultimap object in scala, using TreeMultimap.create method, but can't figure out how to pass type information there([Double, String]).

Any ideas?

As far as I understand I could use TreeMultimap.create() expression in Java for that.

Comment: In general, the type arguments go *before* the actual arguments, e.g. `foo[TypeArgs](actualArgs)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
TreeMultimap.create[java.lang.Double,String]()
```

When I just use `Double` is complains that it's not a `java.lang.Comparable` (since Scala's `Double` is really meant to be Java's `double`).  Using `java.lang.Double` gets around this easily.